# Is there a way to search for HTML tables on a website in Google?

Tags: google-search

I'm an accessibility expert. When auditing a website, I'm usually (among many other things) try to find some tables that don't meet the requirements (e.g. missing `th` elements in data tables).

As it is cumbersome to search for such tables manually, it would be very handy to be able to search for them using google, the same way that (for example) filetype search work:

```
filetype:pdf site:access-for-all.ch
```

I tried a little bit around, and couldn't find a solution. Although Google has a tables search...

https://research.google.com/tables

...I couldn't make it work for me. I tried searching for `"zugang für alle" Audit` and `site:access-for-all.ch preise`, but none of them showed results, although there clearly is a table with "preise" in it on http://www.access-for-all.ch/ch/zertifizierung/kostenuebersicht.html.

Any idea on how this works? And how to make it suit my needs (searching for tables in general)?

Comment: I'm not sure how to accomplish that in Google, but a web programmer could easily code a "website scraper" that looks for both the <table> tag and the <th> tag in any website you choose. In essence, a scraper retrieves the HTML of a web page just like a browser would, but instead of displaying it visually, it analyzes the text of the page that was output.

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265748/search-in-html-source-with-google) on the StackOverflow community. It includes several answers that recommend other web browsers (instead of Google).  Those other web browsers allow you to search the HTML of websites without having to program a scraper.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using an existing accessibility checker?

I would expect at least some of the tools on this list would check table headers for you.

https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tools/

eg http://wave.webaim.org/

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I do know how to test tables for accessibility, my question is: how do I find tables in the first place on a website?

Comment: I see. I will update my answer